# Copy file as raw binary text

Tags: notepad++, file-transfer, zip, copy-paste, sublime-text-2

I do need to copy the [jce_policy-8.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) from my Mac to a Citrix Desktop on Demand. The customer blocked every fileshare and Download. So I have tried to copy the .zip as raw text.

**Source**

I open the jce_policy-8.zip in Sublime on a Mac and copy the raw text.

**Target**

The Desktop on Demand is a Citrix Windows 7 machine. I do paste the raw text in Notepad++ and save it as jce.zip.

I can't open the .zip on the Target machine. The text also looks different than opened in Sublime. Any suggestions?

Comment: generally speaking, if you open up a non-text document, Npp will attempt to encode it with the best fitting scheme it can find for display. That means what you see in the editor is not the actual byte code of the .zip. This is compounded by the copy and re-save. you may want to try using a hex editor instead.

Comment: isn't "binary text" an oxymoron? What's wrong with copying the zip file to a usb / dvd / etc, like a regular file?

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a [Mime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) format.

There are a few ways to do this but try attaching the zip to a new email message on the Mac and then Save-As the message (Choose plain text if given the option).
Emails are in MIME format.

Open the saved message in a text editor and do the Select-All / Copy.
You can then paste into Notepad via the Citrix client.

Save the notepad file and rename it with a .msg extension, Windows should then treat it as an Email message.
Double click the .msg file and the default email client should open it.

It's also possible that you could give it a .zip extension and, if the default archiving program understands MIME, it may open.

If The Mac mail program won't play the game, install Thunderbird, it has Ctrl + U to view the message in full.

Comment: Not working for me !

Comment: What part doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

## Short:

1. ENCODE the content of the zip to Base64 on source host,
2. Copy to target host as text,
3. DECODE the text from Base64 and save as zip

## Long:

### Encode binary ZIP contents to a Base64 string:

- Either use the **Plugins -> MimeTools -> Base64 Encode** feature in Notepad++ 
  (don't forget to select all text beforehand)
- On Unix based systems use bash

```bash
base64 /path/to/file.zip > output.txt
```

### Copy to target host and save as text file

Simply copy and paste the text by any means available (this may be prohobited by the citrix session as well, I'd be interested in what to do then... ;))
Save as text file

### Decode Base64 string to binary file

- Either use the **Plugins -> MimeTools -> Base64 Decode** feature in Notepad++ 
  (don't forget to select all text beforehand)
- On Unix based systems use bash

```bash
base64 --decode /path/to/file.txt > output.zip
```